# How setPostedProducts() function works?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog

When a product is assigned to a category, Its relation is save is `catalog_category_product` table.

But on searching for `setPostedProducts()` it seems like a magic method. So how the data is saved in `catalog_category_product` table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as you suspected `setPostedProducts` is a magic method.
It just does `$category->setData('posted_product', $products)`.
The values set are later retrieved using `getPostedProducts` when the category is saved.

Here is the backtrace.

- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::save();` calls `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::save`
- ...that calls `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::_afterSave`
- ...that calls `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::_saveCategoryProducts`
- that calls `getPostedProducts` and does something with the results.

See the method `_saveCategoryProducts`, specially the part starting with `$products = $category->getPostedProducts();`

**Note:** `$products` is an array where key is a product ID and value is position of product in category.

Comment: Thanks Marius, Now I understood how data is saved in catalog_category_product table.

Comment: does it work on others? i mean, could i use setPostedSlide or something?

Comment: the setter works if your class extends `Varien_Object`. `$object->setPostedSlide()` is equivalent to `$object->setData('posted_slide')`. But it will not auto-magically insert values in your db. You need your custom logic that gets the values you previously set and persists them in the db.

Comment: What I found : `\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryLinkManagement::assignProductToCategories` / `\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryLinkRepository::save` / `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category::_saveCategoryProducts`